# Find two Matrices that are 'almost' similar.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

Let, $J_{k}(\lambda)$ be the Jordan block of size $k$ and eigen value $\lambda$. Then we define,
$$M = J_{5}(0) \oplus J_{2}(0) \oplus J_{2}(0),$$
and
$$M' = J_{5}(0) \oplus J_{1}(0) \oplus J_{3}(0).$$

Observe that, $M$ and $M'$ have the same characteristic polynomial, same eigen values with the same multiplicities, and the same minimal polynomial, but they are not similar because they do not have the same Jordan Canonical Form.

Is my reasoning correct? Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you remove $J_5(0)$ from the definition of $M$ and $M^{'}$?

Comment: @Salcio, so they share the same minimal polynomial.

Comment: @Tobias Yes, that is correct

Comment: @TobiasRieper As an alternative, note that $\operatorname{rank}M^2 = 3$, but $\operatorname{rank}[M']^2 = 4$.

Comment: @Tobias - Ok, but are you saying that to get two matrices with the same characteristic polynomial which are not similar one has to go to order 9?